# What does ANSI mean in the LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO event?

Tags: winapi

The Debug API reports DLL load events through a [LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-load_dll_debug_info) event. One of the structure's data members optionally holds the DLL's file name (`lpImageName`).

The character encoding of this field is described as:

> If `fUnicode` is a nonzero value, the name string is Unicode; otherwise, it is ANSI.

Unicode presumably means UTF-16. Though it's unclear which codepage to use to interpret the ANSI encoding. There are multiple potential contenders (e.g. the originating process' default codepage, the system's codepage, the receiving process' default codepage, the receiving thread's current codepage, etc.).

Which codepage is it?

Comment: Does it not just mean that the info in `lpImageName` should be cast to a `char*` rather than to a `wchar_t*`, as in other uses of "ANSI" *versus* "Unicode" in the Windows API?

Comment: `fUnicode` is hard-coded to be always 1. simply no case when it 0

Comment: `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO` is converted from [`DBGKM_LOAD_DLL`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntdbg.h#L154) and here no any ansi/unicode case. string, if exist, always in unicode. loader in ntdll, before call `ZwMapViewOfSection` (from which this debug event) set `NT_TIB.ArbitraryUserPointer` to dll names as is passed to `LoadLibrary/LdrLoadDll`. of course in case exe or ntdll by self - no this string. and if we map image section by hand.

Comment: Any time the Win32 API uses ANSI strings, the codepage used is typically the one returned by `GetACP()`. So, it would be the user's system codepage at the OS level, not a different codepage at the thread/process level.

Comment: you also can ask, are `dwProcessId` (and `dwThreadId`) - always *identifier of the process in which the debugging event occurred* - in case load/unload dll debug event this can be not true (id of another process/tread can be here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially the debug event comes in the form [`DBGUI_WAIT_STATE_CHANGE`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L187)

if use `WaitForDebugEvent[Ex]` api - it internally convert `DBGUI_WAIT_STATE_CHANGE` to `DEBUG_EVENT` by using [`DbgUiConvertStateChangeStructure[Ex]`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L348)

when section (file mapping in win32 terms) created with `SEC_IMAGE` mapped in process, which is being debugged, the `DbgLoadDllStateChange` message send to debugger. [`DbgUiConvertStateChangeStructure[Ex]`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L348) convert it to `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO`

note that original [`DBGKM_LOAD_DLL`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L145) not containing any info about are in ansi or unicode was *NamePointer*. this is "unknown". the [`DbgUiConvertStateChangeStructure[Ex]`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L348) always hard-code `fUnicode = TRUE`. this string, if exist, always in unicode.

> This member is strictly optional. Debuggers must be prepared to handle
> the case where lpImageName is NULL or *lpImageName (in the address
> space of the process being debugged) is NULL. Specifically, the system
> will never provide an image name for a create process event, and it
> will not likely pass an image name for the first DLL event. The system
> will also never provide this information in the case of debugging
> events that originate from a call to the DebugActiveProcess function.

note, that `lpImageName` is pointer to pointer of a string (`WCHAR** lpImageName` can be say). in current implementation - this is always point to [`NT_TIB.ArbitraryUserPointer`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190418-00/?p=102428) (not containing value of *ArbitraryUserPointer* but address of *ArbitraryUserPointer*)

formally can say `lpImageName = &ptib->ArbitraryUserPointer` where `NT_TIB* ptib`.
so `lpImageName` by self never 0, but `*lpImageName` (of course in target process address space) can be 0. when `LdrLoadDll` (or `LoadLibrary`) load dll, before map image section (call to `ZwMapViewOfSection`) set `ArbitraryUserPointer` to unicode string passed to `LdrLoadDll` as is. and restore original value of *ArbitraryUserPointer* after this. in case image name for a create process event, and image name for the first DLL (ntdll) here (in *ArbitraryUserPointer* 0) also it of course not valid when we receive debug events latter (case of `DebugActiveProcess`). so use `lpImageName` not reliable.

also interesing that in case load and unload image section (this is not always mean dll load/unload) *(dwProcessId, dwThreadId)* not of process/thread in which the debugging event occurred, but process/thread which call [ZwMapViewOfSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) or [ZwUnmapViewOfSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwunmapviewofsection). this is in general case different things, because possible map/unmap section in another process. however this is rarely case, but many debuggers (including windbg and from msvc) wrong handle this case and hung on it